# Jquery validation triggers but doesn't prevent the form submitting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, jquery-validate

I have an MVC project with Knockout.

I'm trying to validate my Register View using jQuery validation.

This is the Register View:

```html
<form data-bind="submit: register" id="formRegister">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input id="registerEmail" name="registerEmail" class="required email form-control" 
           type="text" data-bind="value: registerEmail" />

    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="registerPassword" name="registerPassword" class="required form-control" 
           type="password" data-bind="value: registerPassword" />

    <label>Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="registerPassword2" name="registerPassword2" class="required form-control" 
           type="password" data-bind="value: registerPassword2" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
</form>
```

And the jquery:

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#formRegister").validate();
        $.extend($.validator.messages, { required: "*", email: "Invalid email address." });
    });
});
```

When I submit the form, the validation is triggered but the form is **also being submitted**.

Comment: You need to return false to prevent normal browser form processing. Try to capture the button submit with a click binding, and return false

Comment: @brianlmerritt, thank you, that did it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return false if form is not valid.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#formRegister", function(evt) {
      if(!$(evt.target).valid()) { return false; }
 });
```